# onClick on commandLink set css of image attached with that Link

Tags: javascript, css, jsf-2

I have two `<h:commandLink>` and in each `<h:commandLink>` I placed a `<p:graphicImage>` I want to change width,height of image on `onClick` event.
By default `usFlag` remains active(means bigger than other).
code snippet is given below...

```
<p:commandLink id="usLink" action="#{localeController.switchLocale('en')}">
    <p:graphicImage id="usFlag" value="/resources/images/us-flag.gif" styleClass="activeFlag"/>
</p:commandLink>
<p:commandLink id="frLink" action="#{localeController.switchLocale('fr')}">
    <p:graphicImage id="frFlag" value="/resources/images/fr-flag.gif" styleClass="inActiveFlag"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

I want after clicking on a link will set height,width of that image. I want it to be done using js. How is it possible? Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just set these attributes in the styleClass that is specified in the css?

Comment: @zargarf: thanks for reply, but am I clear to make understand you? Please elaborate what you want to do.

Comment: @Diganta  Your `p:commandLink` will be displayed as an image as per your code. Where is the link?

Comment: @Vikas V : I mean image by link.

Answer (score 0):

You need to dynamically assign the styleClass for the image based on the locale. Create a method in your backing bean e.g.

```
public String getStyleClassForImageLocale(String locale)
{
// if locale = the currently selected locale
// then return "activeFlag"
// else return "inactiveFlag"
}
```

then in your xhtml:

```
<p:commandLink id="usLink" action="#{localeController.switchLocale('en')}">
    <p:graphicImage id="usFlag" value="/resources/images/us-flag.gif" styleClass="#{localeController.getStyleClassForImageLocale('en')"/>
</p:commandLink>
<p:commandLink id="frLink" action="#{localeController.switchLocale('fr')}">
    <p:graphicImage id="frFlag" value="/resources/images/fr-flag.gif" styleClass="#{localeController.getStyleClassForImageLocale('fr')"/>
</p:commandLink>
```

Then in your css file just set the width and height for the style classes .inActiveFlag and .activeFlag

Comment: I also tried this but failed because my localController is in Sessionscope. This code is in login page, so after logout this bean's method will return null (ie. will not work).